# Zabbix internal and external housekeeping

Tags: zabbix

Zabbix configuration in GUI have an "Internal housekeeping" option for some types of data. Anyone can tell me what the difference between internal and external housekeeping? What will be if i am uncheck "Enable internal housekeeping"?

> "It is possible to override the history/trend storage period even if
>   internal housekeeping is disabled. Thus, when using an external
>   housekeeper, the history storage period could be set using the history
>   Data storage period field."

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When internal housekeeping is enabled, Zabbix automatically removes old data, as per the sections in your screenshot. "External housekeeping" is something you would implement yourself and Zabbix would not have knowledge or control over it.

History/trend retention period override controls how the frontend works (disabling those fields in the frontend, controlling how graphs display data in some cases), but does not affect the data retention.

Comment: "External housekeeping" is something you would implement yourself - where you know about it? Dont see in documentation. If i will run zabbix_server -c /usr/local/etc/zabbix_server.conf -R housekeeper_execute like described here: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/concepts/server it would be EXTERNAL housekeeping?

Comment: No idea why it is not described in zabbix docs, they think it is so easy for describing and most people will get it by himself )

Comment: "-R housekeeper_execute" wouldn't be external housekeeping - that would be the same internal one, just manually invoked.

Comment: So, what will be an external?

Comment: There is no single definition of "external housekeeping" - it is just anything that is done outside the knowledge of Zabbix. Whatever trims the data as needed.

Comment: A little late, but maybe external Housekeeping is like database partitioning and manually cleaning/dropping old tables? Would make sense to me as in bigger setups partitioning is the default action to prevent high DB i/o load